# Using "userData.uid" as key

Tags: firebase

firebase is beating me like a mother with no mercy.
Look at my code:

```
ref.createUser({
            email    : $("#email").val(),
            password : $("#senha").val()
        }, function(error, userData) {
            if (error) {
              alert("Nao foi possivel cadastrar: "+error);
            } else {
                ref.child("fornecedores").push({
                    [userData.uid]:{
                        email: $("#email").val(),
                        logo: nome+".jpg",
                        nome: $("#nome").val()
                    }
                },function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                      alert("Nao foi possivel salvar: " + error);
                    } else {
                        alert("Seus dados foram salvos!: "+userData.uid);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Everything works fine, there is no error, but look at my json:
*

```
{
  "fornecedores" : {
    "-K7XNT_UrCyuM4KLfptO" : {
      "5b0beab0-d32a-4115-b346-25a8d3e1fffe" : {
        "email" : "jequiti5@gmail.com",
        "logo" : "J.jpg",
        "nome" : "Jequiti Cosméticos 5"
      }
    },
}
```

*

Why there are two keys??? Where this "-K7X..." came from???

Comment: its a dinamic key from parameter userData of the function

Comment: lol. Yes, sorry. I knew that, I was stating that it's the first piece of data to be written to the node in question. See my answer.

Comment: You're looking for ref.child("fornecedores").child(auth.uid).set(...). See [creating references](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references) and [saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html). Particularly the [section on lists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as Jay said, thanks!!!

```
ref.createUser({
            email    : $("#email").val(),
            password : $("#senha").val()
        }, function(error, userData) {
            if (error) {
                $("#load").css("display","none");
                alert("Nao foi possivel salvar: "+error);
            } else {
                ref.child("fornecedores").child(userData.uid).set({
                    email: $("#email").val(),
                    logo: nome+".jpg",
                    nome: $("#nome").val()
                },function(error) {
                    $("#load").css("display","none");
                    if (error) {
                      alert("Nao foi possivel salvar: " + error);
                    } else {
                        alert("Seus dados foram salvos!: "+userData.uid);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: In that case, click the check mark next to Jay's question to accept it. Also note that StackOverflow is not a forum. Your follow up to Jay's answer shows up above his answer for me. If you have some follow up for Jay, add a comment to his answer. If you think your code makes his answer more useful: edit his answer and add your code to it.

Answer (score 1):

push() auto generates the key to the node and then userData.uid is the child with email, logo and nome as it's children.

From Firebase [Saving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html):

> Every time you call push() your database generates a unique ID, like

```
messages/users/<unique-user-id>/<username>
```

Comment: thanks guys! now I understood, push auto generates a key, so i have to use set because i want the userData.uid as key.

Comment: now i face other problem, when i use 'set' its replace the older, if i use twice just the last appears. What I want is use the 'userData.uid' as key of all my 'fornecedores', but using set its replace the olders.

Comment: I think I have to use push and give up trying to use 'userData.uid' as key

Comment: is there a way to make my uid as a unique ID on web?